# Actionscript 3 calling a Movieclip inside another Movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3

I am currently working on a cricket game, but I am stuck here with a little problem. I have programmed it so the game registers when the ball hits the guy, and then something will happen. However the striker(mcGuy1) contains the bat(mcBat) MovieClip which I want to call. So I want the ball only to do something when it hits the bat movieclip and not the whole guy. This is my code for that:

```
// Function for hitting the bat
function hitBat(event:Event):void
{
    if(mcBall.hitTestObject(mcGuy1)){
        score++
        mcBall2.gotoAndPlay(2);
        mcBall.gotoAndStop(1);
        txtBox2.text = "You hit the ball!";
        myShot2.play();
        txtBox3.text = "Score: " + score;
    }
    else if(mcBall.hitTestObject(mcWall))
    {
        txtBox2.text = "You missed!";
    }
}
```

So instead of hitTestObject mcGuy1, I want it to be hitting the mcBat movieclip.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And how is this related to [tag:batch-file]? please read the tag info before randomly adding tags!

Comment: Wops, my bad must have misclicked that tag. Sorry :s

Comment: Wouldn't the path be simply `mcGuy1.mcBat`? Try `if(mcBall.hitTestObject(mcGuy1.mcBat)){ DO YOUR STUFF }`

Comment: That works, thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to do

```
if(mcBall.hitTestObject(mcGuy1.mcBat))
```

instead of 
    if(mcBall.hitTestObject(mcGuy1))

`mcBat` is a member of `mcGuy1` if it is a child.